# Illegal String offset in php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Hey i am getting  **Illegal string offset** warning in php when i try to store the values from associate array into a table.

When i print the associate array i get this :

Array ( [productName] => iphone [productDesc] => A product from apple [price] => 5 [image] => test/Group/pic.png )

```
   $db1 = new mysqli('localhost',$user,$pass,$db) or die (" Connection failed  ");
   $query="Select productName,productDesc,price,image from product where productID=1";
   $query_first=mysqli_query($db1,$query) or die("Query not retrieved");

   $query_second=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_first);
   //print_r($query_second);
   $rows=mysqli_num_rows($query_first);
   echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr>

             <td> Product Name</td>
             <td> Product Description</td>
             <td> Price</td>
             <td> Image </td>
        </tr> ';

    foreach($query_second as $r)
    {


        echo '<tr><td>'.$r['productName'];
        echo '</td><td>'.$r['productDesc'];
        echo '</td><td>'.$r['price'];
        echo '</td><td>'.$r['image'];
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }//end foreach
   echo"</table>";
```

Comment: place your `mysqli_fetch_assoc` in a while rather than a `foreach`

Comment: the answer you accepted, is exactly what I meant by ^

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

> mysqli_result::fetch_assoc -- mysqli_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row
>   as an associative array

mysqli_mysqli_fetch_assoc returns **ONE single** row from the database.
As you can see in the result of print_r().

The array contains:

```
Array ( [productName] => iphone [productDesc] => A product from apple [price] => 5 [image] => test/Group/pic.png )
```

So when you loop through the array in the first iteration $r will contain a string with value "iphone", second loop "A product from apple" and so on.

In your code you are basically saying "from the STRING iphone give me the character at the position 'productName' ", and as you can guess "productName" is not a valid char position in string.

So you need to iterate every row from the table.

```
<?php
$db1 = new mysqli('localhost',$user,$pass,$db) or die (" Connection failed  ");
$query="Select productName,productDesc,price,image from product where productID=1";
$query_first=mysqli_query($db1,$query) or die("Query not retrieved");

//print_r($query_second);

echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>

     <td> Product Name</td>
     <td> Product Description</td>
     <td> Price</td>
     <td> Image </td>
</tr> ';


while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_first)) {

    echo '<tr><td>'.$r['productName'];
    echo '</td><td>'.$r['productDesc'];
    echo '</td><td>'.$r['price'];
    echo '</td><td>'.$r['image'];
    echo '</td></tr>';
}//end foreach
echo"</table>";

?>
```

If you just want 1 single row then you dont need interation

```
<?php
$db1 = new mysqli('localhost',$user,$pass,$db) or die (" Connection failed  ");
$query="Select productName,productDesc,price,image from product where productID=1";
$query_first=mysqli_query($db1,$query) or die("Query not retrieved");

//print_r($query_second);

echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>

     <td> Product Name</td>
     <td> Product Description</td>
     <td> Price</td>
     <td> Image </td>
</tr> ';


$r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_first);

echo '<tr><td>'.$r['productName'];
echo '</td><td>'.$r['productDesc'];
echo '</td><td>'.$r['price'];
echo '</td><td>'.$r['image'];
echo '</td></tr>';

echo"</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Edit: sorry bad copy paste :D

Comment: The image column in the table contains the location of the image file , how would i display that ?

Comment: `echo "</td><td><imt src='" . $r['image'] . "' alt='' />";`

Comment: Mark the question as answered, to let people know.

Comment: I cannot retrive the image , I am using XAMP to run locally . 
i am storing the image in htdocs i.e(htdocs/pictures/pic.jpg) and the value stored in the image field is pictures/pic.jpg

Comment: `echo "</td><td><imt src='htdocs/" . $r['image'] . "' alt='' />";`

Comment: syntax is `<img` and not `<imt`

Comment: Yea sorry my bad ... 10x Fred

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_fetch_assoc returns a row so you don't need to loop through it with:

```
foreach($query_second as $r)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php